# Something's wrong with my login feature, I used okta with google oauth2

Tags: jhipster, okta

I use Okta to securiry my jhipster app.

I am trying to follow this guide [Create an App at the Identity Provider
Google](https://developer.okta.com/docs/guides/add-an-external-idp/google/create-an-app-at-idp/) and I config `response_type: code`

It works fine, but i get `#code=ovy8omeh8NdmAl47iZ7BeS9YvAaPAfMYqBIed-evSxk&state=WM6D` without logging in

When I click login again, I can login

Please help me! thanks very much

Comment: Are there any messages in your browser's developer console?

Comment: @MattRaible thank Matt, i just see `Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 401 (Unauthorized)` at `api/account`. And, When I press login again, I get the user information and logged in.

Comment: It seems strange that you're seeing `code=ovy8omeh8NdmAl47iZ7BeS9YvAaPAfMYqBIed-evSxk&state=WM6D` in your address bar after logging in. This should be sent to Spring Security on your backend, not appearing on your frontend. I did recently configure social login with an Okta hosted widget and a custom domain. Maybe this will help? https://developer.okta.com/blog/2020/09/21/ionic-apple-google-signin